# How to get seperated lines from txt file

Tags: python

I need to get first line from one txt file (accountfile.txt) into another text file (errorfile.txt) when a specific error occurs.. Right now its just adding the whole txt file instead of just the first line

```
def get_account():
with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'settings'), 'accountfile.txt'), 'r') as file:
    account = [i.strip() for i in file]
    if account:
        return account

def add_error():

account = get_account()

with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'settings'), 'errorfile.txt'), 'w') as file:
    file.write('{}:error\n'.format(erroraccount)
```

What do i need to change in the def add_error() section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `[i.strip() for i in file]`, you are getting all the lines in the file. what you want is only the first.

Use this fixed code:

```
def get_account():
with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'settings'), 'accountfile.txt'), 'r') as file:
    account = [i.strip() for i in file][0]
    if account:
        return account
```

Or better, use this:

```
def get_account():
with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'settings'), 'accountfile.txt'), 'r') as file:
    account = file.readline()
    if account:
        return account
```

`file.readline()` reads the first line, which is what you need.

## Edit

The following code reads and deletes the first line from `accountfile` and then writes this line to `errorfile`:

```
with open('/Users/ammar/Desktop/x.txt', 'r') as f_acc:
    lines = f_acc.readlines()

with open('/Users/ammar/Desktop/x.txt', 'w') as f_acc, \
    open ('/Users/ammar/Desktop/xx.txt', 'w') as f_err:
    f_acc.write(''.join(lines[1:]))
    f_err.write('{}:error\n'.format(lines[0].strip()))
```

I can't tell if this is the "best" way, but it works as long as `accountfile` has text into it.

Comment: Whats the best way to remove that one line from the accountfile.txt now that its been added to the errorfile.txt ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include what you described

Answer (score 0):

The method `readline()`reads one entire line from the file.

```
fline = file.readline()
```